Irreducibility for polynomial $-x^p+ax+b$ if $a|b$
Motivated by the research I did to find an answer to my question here about integer roots of some polynomial, I discovered the Eisenstein criterion on the coefficients of a polynomial.
Consider a polynomial  $Q(x)=-x^p+ax+b$, $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $a|b$ and every prime factor of $a$ at least twice in its prime factor decomposition. This is a very concrete case, where the Eisenstein criterion does not work, since $a_1, a_0$ have to be divisible by some prime $p$ but $a_0$ not by $p^2$.
Is there another criterion which could apply in this case? Or does anyone know results on this type of polynomial (generalization of depressed cubic)?
Nonetheless, trying to find integer zeros via $-x^p+ax+b=0$ and writing $b=ac$, I find that $x^p=a(x+c)$. Consequently, $x^p$ has to be divisible by $a$. Here I get stuck.
Can in this case more be said about integer zeros of $Q$?

If you're asking about zeros of the polynomial, the rational root theorem answers this question for you. Of course, the polynomial may still be reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ even if it doesn't have any integer zeros (provided $p > 3$).
